# Why can't redirect tee command's stdout into /dev/null

Tags: bash, redirect

I make fingerprint for all files in `/var/www/html` this way.

```
find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori
```

It works fine.

Now i want to redirect all stdout of tee command into /dev/null.

```
find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori  1>/dev/null

md5sum: /var/www/html/news/uploads/Red: No such file or directory
md5sum: Hat: No such file or directory
md5sum: Enterprise: No such file or directory
md5sum: Linux: No such file or directory
md5sum: 6.txt: No such file or directory
```

I found thant a file name can't be parsed properly.

```
ls /var/www/html/news/uploads/Red*
/var/www/html/news/uploads/Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.txt
```

How to fix my command to properly redirect stdout into /dev/null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
find /var/www/html -type  f | xargs -i md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori  1>/dev/null
```

From `xargs`'s manual:

> **-I** replace-str
>
> Replace  occurrences  of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character.  Implies -x and -L
>                 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your stdout redirection is working fine, and is unrelated to the error message you are getting (which is on standard error, not standard output, anyway.  If you want to discard stderr that's `2>/dev/null`).

The reason for the error is that you are passing unquoted file names to `md5sum`. A common workaround with GNU `find` is to use zero-byte terminators instead of newlines:

```
find /var/www/html -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 md5sum |
tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori >/dev/null
```

Of course, there is no need to `tee` anything if you discard the standard output.

```
find /var/www/html -type  f -print0 | 
xargs -0 md5sum >/opt/figerprint.db.ori
```

A common addition is `xargs -r` to prevent `md5sum` from running at all if `find` doesn't find any files.

The error message suggests that you probably *don't* have GNU `find`. Another way to accomplish the same thing is

```
find /var/www/html -type f -exec md5sum {} + >/opt/figerprint.db.ori
```

If your `find` is really ancient and doesn't support `-exec ... +` you will need to switch to

```
find /var/www/html -type f -exec md5sum {} \; >/opt/figerprint.db.ori
```

which is however going to be rather inefficient, because it creates one process per found file.

Answer (score 0):

Why `find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori` can't show error info?

```
find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum
md5sum: /var/www/html/news/uploads/Red: No such file or directory
md5sum: Hat: No such file or directory
md5sum: Enterprise: No such file or directory
md5sum: Linux: No such file or directory
md5sum: 6.txt: No such file or directory
```

`tee` will show both stdout and stderr on screen but only write stdout info by default.

```
find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori
```

I go through the output of the above command in the screen ,

```
md5sum: /var/www/html/news/uploads/Red: No such file or directory
md5sum: Hat: No such file or directory
md5sum: Enterprise: No such file or directory
md5sum: Linux: No such file or directory
md5sum: 6.txt: No such file or directory
```

The above lines(call it related error info) were emcircled by many other lines such as

```
b61b25303be0f573a6b9446d5cbe3a5b  /var/www/html/index.php
```

The related error info can't be written into file by default (tee's character).

`find /var/www/html  -type  f |xargs md5sum | tee /opt/figerprint.db.ori` never works fine.